# Access to multiple nested dictionaries to return a minimum key and value

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I have a list containing 4 dicts:

```
Epsom = [HorseA, HorseB, HorseC, HorseD]
```

Each one of these dicts is composed as follows:

```
for x in Epsom:
    print(x)

{'HorseA': {'jay': 0.8, 'john': 0.3, 'paul': 0.7, 'peter': 0.2}}
{'HorseB': {'jay': 0.4, 'john': 0.2, 'paul': 0.1, 'peter': 0.9}}
{'HorseC': {'jay': 0.8, 'john': 0.1, 'paul': 0.9, 'peter': 0.7}}
{'HorseD': {'jay': 0.6, 'john': 0.3, 'paul': 0.4, 'peter': 0.1}}
```

I want to iterate through `Epsom` and return each Horse name and the lowest value offered for it -- thats including people offering the same lowest number for the horse. This is as far as I have gotten:

```
for x in Epsom:
    horse_temp = x.keys()
    temp_dict = x.values()
    low_odds = min(temp_dict.values())
    print('Horse: {} -- Lowest Odds: {}'.format(horse_temp, low_odds))
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#144>", line 4, in <module>
low_odds = min(temp_dict.values())
AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I think I am treating the result of `temp_dict.values()` wrongly (obviously). I thought that by using `.values()`, I would be returning a dict.

Ultimately, I'd like to get a clean format returned (some of my prints were including things such as `Horse: [dict_keys(['HorseA'])] Lowest Odds: dict_values([{'jay': 0.8, 'john': 0.3, 'paul': 0.7, 'peter': 0.2}])`

I'd like it to look like this (for example):

```
Horse: HorseA -- Lowest Odds: John 0.3, Paul 0.3
Horse: HorseB -- Lowest Odds: Peter 0.2
Horse: HorseC -- Lowest Odds: Jay 0.8, Paul 0.8
Horse: HorseD -- Lowest Odds: John 0.3
```

Any help would be appreciated. Am I doing this the right way from a structural point of view using a list with dict nested in it? Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @albert said. Also note that `<dict>.keys()` also returns a list-like object. So if you want horse names to be strings, you can't just use the result of `.keys()` (see the code below).

Here's a full solution:

```
for horse in epsom:
    horse_name, = horse.keys()  # same as: horse_name = horse.keys()[0]
    offers, = horse.values()    # same as: offers = horse.values()[0]
    min_odds = min(offers.values())
    lowest = ((k, v) for k, v in offers.items() if v == min_odds)
    formatted_lowest = ', '.join('{} {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in lowest)
    print('Horse: {} -- Lowest Odds: {}'.format(horse_name, formatted_lowest))
```

Note `epsom` instead of your `Epsom`. You should name your variables in lower case. That's the [prevailing convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).

> Am I doing this the right way from a structural point of view using a
>   list with dict nested in it?

This is impossible to answer without knowing the larger context of your problem. But I wonder why you nest the dicts inside a list rather than inside a dict. If you had

```
epsom = {
    'HorseA': {'jay': 0.8, 'john': 0.3, 'paul': 0.7, 'peter': 0.2},
    'HorseB': {'jay': 0.4, 'john': 0.2, 'paul': 0.1, 'peter': 0.9},
    'HorseC': {'jay': 0.8, 'john': 0.1, 'paul': 0.9, 'peter': 0.7},
    'HorseD': {'jay': 0.6, 'john': 0.3, 'paul': 0.4, 'peter': 0.1}
}
```

You'd have less nesting, and looping would be more straightforward:

```
for horse_name, offers in sorted(epsom.items()):
    min_odds = min(offers.values())
    lowest = ((k, v) for k, v in offers.items() if v == min_odds)
    formatted_lowest = ', '.join('{} {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in lowest)
    print('Horse: {} -- Lowest Odds: {}'.format(horse_name, formatted_lowest))
```

Comment: Gill, thank you very much. That works GREAT! And I have no idea why I used a list -- dict makes much more sense as you point out.

Answer (score 0):

`<dict>.values()` is returning a so called `dict_value` object which is comparable to the datatype `list`.

So you should do something like

```
low_odds = min(temp_dict)
```

In addition, you should rename your variables since those aren't `dict`s at all and that might be confusing when reading your code.